# Reverse lookup of Terminal Services Home Folder withDirectory Services

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm looking for a way to query the Terminal Services Home Folder property of user objects in Active Directory. My goal is to be able to perform a reverse lookup, finding the user(s) that use a particular home folder.

Normally to perform a search I would do something like this:

```
using (var search = new DirectorySearcher())
{
    // Find a user based on their telephone number
    search.Filter = "(telephoneNumber=999)"; 
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
    var result = search.FindOne();
    if(result != null) {....}
}
```

But the Terminal Services settings don't seem to have a referable LDAP attribute name - in the past to *set* these values I've had to use the IADsTSUserEx interface with an existing DirectoryEntry to manipulate the TS profile and home folder properties. However this is only useful when I have the user account in question - it's not very practical to step through every user in a domain and create a DirectoryEntry object for them just to check their TS profile path.

Is there any practical way to perform a "WHERE User.TerminalServicesProfilePath=X" query in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody here so, I try an explanation.

In Windows Server 2008 (and R2), the Terminal Services Terminal Server Runtime Interface takes the user parameters from the user Active-Directory attribute called `userParameters`. [As explain in Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc669440%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx) documentation `userParameter` contains [Terminal Server parameter as blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635189%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Oddly the propValue documentation doesn't seem to match what I get (everything else about the dictionary structure is right). I found I had to use this to get the values to decode correctly: http://daduke.org/linux/userparameters.html